# Does Google/Bing/HERE Maps Autosuggestion Make Request for Every Keystroke?

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, bing-maps, here-api

I've noticed that Map services mention how different types of requests count towards an application's quota, but didn't see how autocomplete requests compare.

I'm trying to calculate the number of transactions/requests that will be made if an application utilizes an autocomplete feature for address searches. What I wanted to know is that when a user enters an address for geocoding, every time a new list of suggestions is returned (i.e. for every keystroke) is it counted as a request -- i.e. does it count as multiple requests instead of a single request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bing Maps, the way it works is that a transaction isn't created until the user has selected a suggestion. Individual keystrokes are not counted. At the end of the day its the suggestion the user selects that matters. Additionally, Bing Maps also creates a session when that first transaction is created. What this does is if the user performs another search and selects another suggestion, the second transaction will be marked as non-billable as it is considered part of that session. This assumes that the autosuggest module wasn't reloaded some how (i.e. page refresh). So with Bing Maps, if a user needs 3 key strokes or 7, there is no cost until they actually select a suggestion. This should make calculating the required transactions for your application much easier. More often than not developers will require the user to use the autosuggest feature only once as part of a user experience, usually on a single page. So you basically would only need to know the number of page views for the page in that part of the user experience. Also worth noting, if you use the autosuggest module in Bing Maps with the interactive map, the autosuggest module will not generate any billable transactions as it is grouped into the map user session. For example, if you have a page that loads a map and also provides an autosuggest box, the user can type as much as they want in the autosuggest box and select as many suggestions as they want. They can also pan/zoom, calculate directions and use any feature of Bing Maps that you expose in your app. This will generate a total of 1 billable transaction for when the interactive map was loaded and all other transactions will be grouped into the map session and marked as non-billable.

Looking through HERE Maps documentation I can't find any mention of an autosuggest or autocomplete feature.